# Only one of two ethernet connections has internet access

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, ethernet

Alright, this one has got me completely stumped. Among other devices, I have three computers currently connected to the same wireless router:

One of them is connected through ethernet and has internet access.

One is connected to the wireless network and has internet access.

The third, despite having no problems connecting with wireless or wired networks in the past, cannot establish a connection with the wireless network. After connecting an ethernet cable, it had internet access for a short time. Now, despite the network still showing a connection and internet access, any attempt to actually access the internet fails.

I've tried all the basic stuff like reconnecting cables and resetting routers with no change. Any insight into what's going on here and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try more basic stuffs like ping router / compare Details of ethernet connections(from different computers) / maybe disable firewall or other similar software.

Comment: Try using the same port as computer that has internet connection.

Comment: Make sure that all 3 computers have **different** IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of steps you can take to diagnose where the error might be occurring.

In laymans terms you want to diagnose whether this is a physical problem (cabling) or a configuration issue. In technical terms you want to discern whether this is a layer 1/2 or a layer 3 issue.

When you connect to the router ensure that you are able to ping the local gateway and the access point. This can be accomplished by opening a command prompt and typing ipconfig /all to determine the local gateway /AP IP address, then running 'ping x.x.x.x' - where x is equal to the switch or routers IP address.

In my experience, these kinds of issues are caused by the AP or router DHCP server assigning the same IP address to two hosts. Simply assigning each host a static IP address usually solves it. This can be accomplished by going to the TCP/IP settings through the Network and Sharing Centre in the systray>Adaptor Properties>Rightclick on relevant adaptor>TCP/IP (v4) and setting the address manually. You may need to get DNS information from your router.

So what you want to do is basically ensure you can reach the router from the host connecting wirelessly from the wireless access point (AP). If you can reach the router then double check in ipconfig on both hosts to ensure that both hosts aren't getting assigned the same IP address.

Comment: Well... Went to go try this and apparently it had already spontaneously started working. Keeping this marked in case it acts up again, though. Thanks!